# search for facebook fan pages by category using graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Does anyone know how to search for facebook fan pages in a specific categpry using the graph api?

I'm looking to find all fan pages in the automotive category and return their page id's.

Thanks

Jonathan

Answer (score 4):

Think I need to take a different approach and seacrh by automotive maufacturer / brand. Something like this [graph.facebook.com/search?q=audi&type=page](http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=audi&type=page)

Comment: I got error: `{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
   }
}` while opening this into the browser. How can i pass my access token?

Comment: Use Graph API Explorer and query again, like that you will have an access token granted.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Graph API you can only get to list the pages the current user: See: 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/ has page category, so get a complete list of the page.

The FQL page table has a categories array property on it called `categories`, but to get that information you already need to know the page name or the page id.

There is no documented way to globally query the page table by category.

Comment: that's what I figured, I searched high and low. Think I need to take a different approach and seacrh by automotive maufacturer  / brand. Something like this https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=audi&type=page

Answer (score 2):

This may be of use to others having problems with search queries and refining results by categorization.

After your search query append a space and the category name, and your search should become more refined.

Here you will notice that only items in the Musician/Band category are returned:

`http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=wilco%20musician/band&type=page`

It works best when the category is a fairly unique string. This particular search is not as flawless, but still an improvement:

`http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=audi%20automotive&type=page`

You will then need to strip out other categories manually.

Comment: I think facebook shut off public access to the topics search part of the graph api