# search bands/artists pages on facebook API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When creating a Facebook page, I see where people can specify that their page is for an artist/band.  Is it possible for me to use the API to get a list back of all the band/artist pages?  For example if I wanted to get a list of all the bands/artists in the U.S. with FB pages, is that possible using the FB API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible via the Graph API. You can find out what category a particular page belongs to, but you can't query by category, so you need to know about the page first. See this question for more detail: [search for facebook fan pages by category using graph api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964222/search-for-facebook-fan-pages-by-category-using-graph-api)

However, it is possible to query pages via FQL and return information about page that match the "musician/band" category, here's an example query (click to run):

[`SELECT name FROM page WHERE CONTAINS("musician/band")`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=SELECT%20name%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20CONTAINS(%22musician%5Cband%22))

Full details about what you can get from the `page` table in FQL can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page).

Comment: Thanks as that does allow me to grab the list of names, thanks!  The one odd thing I notice is the results.  Seems to be random.  If I don't specify, it returns 100, I then specified 4000 and it returned 235.  Is there a way to get them all and page through them?

Comment: This topic is addressed in a blog post by Facebook here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/